# BadValueError: Property X must be a str or unicode instance, not a tuple (on update, not on creation)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

GAE is driving me crazy.

I have the following:

```
    if id_puertas[x]:
        puerta = Puerta.get_by_id(int(id_puertas[x]))
        puerta.ubicacion = ubicacion_puertas[x],
        puerta.ancho = float(ancho_puertas[x]),
        puerta.marco = float(marco_puertas[x]),
        puerta.alto  = float(alto_puertas[x]),
        puerta.giro  = giro_puertas[x],
        puerta.condena = True if condena_puertas[x] == 'Si' else False,
        puerta.extra = extra_puertas[x]
    else:
        puerta = Puerta(
            medicion = medicion.key().id(),
            ubicacion = ubicacion_puertas[x],
            ancho = float(ancho_puertas[x]),
            marco = float(marco_puertas[x]),
            alto  = float(alto_puertas[x]),
            giro  = giro_puertas[x],
            condena = True if condena_puertas[x] == 'Si' else False,
            extra = extra_puertas[x]
        )
    puerta.put()
```

The same form sends either `id_puerta` as a number, or blank. If it's a number, updates an entity in the datastore. If it's blank, creates a new entity.

Creation works perfectly.

But if I resend the same form (even without modifications) the update chokes on the first assignment.

`ubicacion_puertas[x]` is a string (the same string on creation than on update), and `puerta.ubicacion` is a `StringProperty,` but I receive the following error:

```
 BadValueError: Property ubicacion must be a str or unicode instance, not a tuple
```

In the debugger I see clearly that `ubicacion_puertas[0]` is u'Salon'. so I can't make sense of this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
puerta.ubicacion=ubicacion_puertas[x],
```

you're storing a tuple in the `ubicacion` attribute of `puerta`: another more readable form is:

```
puerta.ubicacion=(ubicacion_puertas[x],)
```

Are you sure this is what you want? Just get rid of the `,` to store a str

```
puerta.ubicacion = ubicacion_puertas[x]
```

(the same goes for the other attributes...)

Comment: Argh! Thanks. Stupid commas a left over from copy & paste. Being syntactically correct nothing jumped off the code as being "wrong", and by staring at the code for too long I managed not to see them. And mixing up different languages with different end-of-line conventions doesn't help either.

Comment: I'm sure we all experienced a "death by trailing comma" at one point or another...